# What is anonymous closure and why is it different from normal closure?

Tags: javascript

I started reading this: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

And they refer to anonymous closure:

> This is the fundamental construct that makes it all possible, and
>   really is the single best feature of JavaScript. We'll simply create
>   an anonymous function, and execute it immediately. All of the code
>   that runs inside the function lives in a closure, which provides
>   **privacy** and **state** throughout the lifetime of our application.

```
(function () {
    // ... all vars and functions are in this scope only
    // still maintains access to all globals
}());
```

- I don't understand what happens in a self-executing anonymous
  function closure-wise, that is different from a normal closure and
  why is it so special?
- What is the benefit in it?

Comment: What does *normal closure* means exactly to you?

Comment: *"I don't understand what happens...that is different from a normal closure"* Nothing is different. It's just a one-time-use function. Only "benefit" is that there's no variable added to the enclosing scope.

Comment: OK thanx, I think my question wasn't clear enough, but I got the answer I wanted by @abresas

Comment: Your question was very clear. People just didn't bother to read it. There's [one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9647079/1106925) that seemed to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables that are not defined within a closure get into the window variable and are global.

Example:

```
var SOME_CONSTANT = 4;

function foo() { 
    var c = SOME_CONSTANT;
    console.log( c );
}

foo();
```

If you have this code, SOME_CONSTANT will be global to all files and code run within inline scripts etc, which may not be desired.

You can use the self-calling closure to keep the variable only inside this closure:

```
( function() {
    var SOME_CONSTANT = 4;

    function foo() {
        var c = SOME_CONSTANT;
        console.log( c );
    }

    foo();

} () );
```

This way you can have modules that have variables global only to that module. For example, by having the code of each file enclosed in such an anonymous function.

Comment: please comment when you down vote so that I know what I do wrong :)

Comment: Just to add, one case where this is particularly important is when developing javascript that will be placed in environments where you have little or no control.  Should you use variables on the window object, they can be overwritten and thus break your code.  The anonymous function will protect any variables you declare within that enclosure.

Comment: You haven't answered the question. The asker already knows everything you've explained.

Comment: @am not i am, what @ Shane added was helpful to me. @ abresas, I've added `foo()` to the second example since there we want to execute it too, right?

Comment: @am not i am, then I probably misunderstood the question. Happy to hear that at least the examples and comment helped. llyaD right!

Answer (score 1):

there is no difference to a "normal closure" besides the fact, that this function is executed immediately.